# Why sharp resonance corresponds to a particle?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, oscillators, resonance, quasiparticles

First picture below is from last section of 23th chapter of Feynman's Lectures on physics.  I don't understand the red line.

This section talks about resonance in nature. It was very interesting and I understood what transparency was all about. But in the last example, I don't understand why the sharp resonance corresponds to a particle.

First, like a simple harmonic vibration (second picture below), we know that the square of the amplitude is
$$
\rho^2=\frac{F^2}{m^2[(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2 +\gamma^2\omega^2]}
$$
Therefore, sharp corresponds to the drag coefficient. The smaller $\gamma$  is, the sharper it is (If we don't consider $m$). So, why it corresponds to a very definite energy ?

Second, I know different particle has different energy in mean $E=mc^2$, where $m$  is the mass of motion. But the energy  of the resonant point is not the energy of the particle. Is there a one-to-one correspondence between them?

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: The horizontal axis is the energy; if a resonance peak is very sharp, that means that the energy of stuff in this resonance is spread out very little, i.e. a very definite energy. As long as you measured something corresponding to these sharp peaks, you know that the energy of those measurements is very close to the peak's horizontal value. It will thus make sense to assert that there is a particle of a definite energy equal to the resonant energy value; further study into quantum theory is needed to tell you why.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent  Thank you. I just started my physics studies. I haven't learned quantum theory yet. So, it's enough for you to tell me there's a connection.

Comment: The "particle" language is one of the less fortunate historical developments of physics. What we mean by "particle" in this context is a combination of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges that can be detected in an experiment. High energy physicist call that signature incorrectly "a particle". If you were to drill down to the basic ontology of quantum mechanics then it's not a very good idea to identify that energy with anything that has "object" character, but in practice it doesn't matter unless you are trying to do philosophy of physics.

Comment: You might profit from [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit–Wigner_distribution).